# SQL Server - Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and underneath, there is a constraints folder. How can I view the constraints in that folder? I didn't see a modify constraint to where I can view it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by *modify constraint* ??

If you're talking about SQL Server Management Studio and its Object Explorer - you can right-click on the `Constraints` node for any given table and choose `Add constraint` - is that what you're looking for??

If you want to change an existing constraint. you need to click on that constraint and typically you need to script that out to drop and then re-create that constraint

[image]

You cannot just modify it "in place" (there's no `Modify Constraint` dialog box or anything like that).

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click it and choose script as Create to a new query window to see what it is.